# Send python requests fast as possible

Tags: python, http, python-requests

this is my current code. It sends around 2300 requests per second.

```
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor

import requests
counter = 0
from timer import timer

URL = 'https://httpbin.org/uuid'
def print_result(result):
    global counter
    print(counter, ' ', result, end='\r')

def fetch(session, url):
    with session.get(url) as response:
        global counter
        counter+=1
        print_result(response.status_code)


@timer(1, 10)
def main():
    with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=450) as executor:
        with requests.Session() as session:
            executor.map(fetch, [session] * 400, [URL] * 400)
            executor.shutdown(wait=False)
```

Is there anyway to make it faster / more stable?

Comment: why do you create more workers than you have tasks (450 workers for 400 tasks)? In general however, async code is considered faster and lighter weight than threads. Unfortunately `requests` doesn't support async, so you may have to use something like `aiohttp`. Async code also requires some careful thought to make sure it runs in an efficient manner, or else you won't see the full benefit.

Comment: What is the purpose behind hammering the httpbin.org site for new UUIDs?

Comment: run code on server which has faster CPU and faster access to Internet.

Comment: running 450 workers doesn't have to make it faster because other processes in system may have blocked access to CPU and it may slow down system functions.

Comment: module [httpx](https://www.python-httpx.org/) is simlar to `requests and it uses `async`